# Generate unique index from existing nonunique index pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with an index like this:

```
foo
bar
spam
eggs
foo
bar
spam
eggs
```

I can access values by using `df.loc['foo', 'column'][0]`, but if I try to set values in the way I get a `SettingWithCopyWarning`. I need to keep the word descriptions in the index, so is there a way of generating a new index that looks like this?:

```
foo
bar
eggs
spam
foo_1
bar_1 ... etc.
```

Comment: why not , just do `reset_index()` and work with int index

Comment: @eshirvana I can be fairly sure that foo_1 will occur after foo, but I can't be sure of the order of foo, bar, eggs and spam. Hence why I'm addressing them by name.

Comment: not sure if i understood but does `df.index += df.index.to_series().groupby(level=0).cumcount().astype(str).radd("_").replace("_0", "")` address the issue? it  groups index values and puts _1, _2 to the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `groupby` with `cumcount`

```
df.index += df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().mask(lambda x : x==0,'').astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=["bar","spam","eggs","foo"])
#df:
bar
spam
eggs
foo


df['new_col'] = df.index + '_1'
#this will keep the index as it is, and add duplicate column with '_1' suffix
        new_col
bar     bar_1
spam    spam_1
eggs    eggs_1
foo     foo_1
```